# PHP Detect if any URL variables have been set

Tags: php

Hey guys, it's kind of hard to explain but basically I want to detect if any variables have been set through the URL. So with my IF statement all of the following should return true:

- http://domain.com/index.php?m=100
- http://domain.com/index.php?q=harhar
- http://domain.com/index.php?variable=poo&crazy=yes

and all the following return false:

- http://domain.com/index.php
- http://domain.com/test.php
- http://domain.com/no_variables.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would test for `QUERY_STRING`:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]))
```

should in effect be no different from checking `$_GET`, though - either way is fine.

Comment: I like this as it will discover: http://example.com/foo.php?thisisaquery. Notice the lack of equal signs.

Comment: @jmuchhiello true, but even in that case `thisisaquery` should be present in `$_GET` as an empty entry if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: As always another excellent answer from @Pekka: Subtle difference makes it more correct than other answers

Comment: My answer is actually correct. The difference is too small. Anyway, @Pekka, nice answer.

Comment: @Josh thanks, but it's not always that way! I'm glad about the "delete" button sometimes :) @Jacob yup, it'll work either way.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, your answer is also correct. I upvoted that one as well.

Comment: @Pekka is `strlen` faster than `empty`?

Comment: @Jacob I don't have the benchmarks handy but I strongly doubt it.

Comment: @Jacob random benchmark says `empty()` is faster: http://maettig.com/code/php/php-performance-benchmarks.php good point. I tend to distrust `empty()` for checks of system variables for some reason (irrational suspicion of whitespaces :) but there is no real reason for it. Changed, cheers.

Answer (score 5):

```
if( !empty( $_GET ) ) {
   //GET variables have been set
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(count($_GET) > 0)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with the exception of (a) variable(s), use this if statement before it checks it:

```
if (!isset($_GET['getvariable'])) {
    if (!empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])) {
        echo "do something";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean taking a string and checking if it has a query string, you can use [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

If you mean checking if the current request has a query string,  you can just check the length of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

If you mean to get a count of the number of variables parsed from the query string, you can do `count($_GET);`

Answer (score -2):

`isset($_GET['m'])`

or if anything, I believe `count($_GET)` might work.

Comment: Yeh but I don't know what the variables are going to be called, that's my point.